# Nokogiri gem build error failed to build gem native extension on WSL with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im using WSL (ubuntu) for windows 10 with RVM version 1.29.12. 
Ruby version is 2.4.1p11. Bundler version  1.16.4.

When I execute bundle install, It stops on nokogiri and throws this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.1
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.4
Using activesupport 5.1.4
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.1
Installing nokogiri 1.8.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking if the C compiler accepts ... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
pkg-config could not be used to find libxml-2.0
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

pkg-config could not be used to find libxslt
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

pkg-config could not be used to find libexslt
Please install either `pkg-config` or the pkg-config gem per

    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"

ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure `pkg-config` is installed.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-libxml-2.0-config
        --without-libxml-2.0-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libxslt-config
        --without-libxslt-config
        --with-exslt-dir
        --without-exslt-dir
        --with-exslt-include
        --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
        --with-exslt-lib
        --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libexslt-config
        --without-libexslt-config

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /mnt/c/Users/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /mnt/c/Users/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /mnt/c/Users/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  view_source_map was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
              nokogiri
```

I have tried several suggestions I found online like doing

```
    gem install pkg-config -v "~> 1.1"
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

but I can't seem to get rid of the error.

I also tried installing the nokogiri separately and then executed bundle install again but the same issue still occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is instructing bundler to look for libraries

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

If above doesn't work. check your log files. In most scenarios some libraries are missed.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your response however I still get the same error.